# Delete vim config and plugin files

Tags: vim

Simple mappings like `let mapleader = ","` don't seem to be working, so I reinstalled vim and removed all plugins. Yet some mappings like this still don't work. Where can I find vim plugin config files? I've looked in `~/.vim` and `~/.config`. When I type a comma in command mode, instead of starting the mapleader command, my mac gives me an alarm bell sound. I included `let mapleader = ","` as the first line in my `.vimrc`.

**UPDATE** To help diagnose, I have this line in my `.vimrc`:

```
noremap <silent> <Leader>w :w<CR>
```

When I type `:map` in vim, I see, among other mappings:

```
,w          * :w<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try placing your mappings in a file called `~/.vimrc`.

The `~/.vim` directory is used to store plugin files, whereas the `~/.vimrc` file is typically used for generic settings like mappings.

Comment: I'm very familiar with my `.vimrc`. I'm talking about vim plugin config files.

Answer (score 3):

The most elaborate information you'll get by running vim via `vim -V`.

This will give you information on every file that vim looks for, finds and opens.

The most important are `~/.vimrc` and `/usr/share/vim/*`.

Besides, please verify that your `mapleader` command is at the beginning of your `vimrc`.

From the manual:

```
Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is
defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined
mappings.
```

EDIT

To verify if it's enabled for sure, type `:let mapleader` in a running vim. It should print something like `mapleader          ,`. Please verify it, so we can think of other causes.

Comment: Thanks, done. `vim -V` didn't show anything I noticed to be undesirable, and a grep for `mapleader` in `/usr/share/vim` showed `mapleader` matches only in documentation files. What else can I try?

Comment: It prints `mapleader              ,`

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined mappings.

Are you sure you are defining map leader before you create your mappings? If not, your mapleader is probably `,` just as your define, but all your macros will be mapped to `\`.

Comment: My mapleader definition is the first line in my `.vimrc`. The backslash in command mode also does nothing but cause my mac alarm bell to beep.

Comment: Can you check your mappings? `:cmap` by itself should tell you everything that you have for command mode.

Answer (score 1):

A Vim plugin usually "configures itself" in `~/.vim/plugin/pluginname.vim`, not in an external file. The configuration typically consists of *variables* (e.g. `g:pluginnameSettingName`) and mappings, which should appear in this format:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(PluginMapping) :<C-u>call pluginname#MyFunc()<CR>
if ! hasmapto('<Plug>(PluginMapping)', 'n')
    nmap <Leader>x <Plug>(PluginMapping)
endif
```

If the default mapping starts with `<Leader>`, your intended change via `:let mapleader` should work. Alternatively, you can try to explicitly override the mapping by mapping your own keys to the `<Plug>...` mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you use a practical plugin [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) to manage your vim plugins. It would enable you to manage your plugins in text format and config parameters of each plugins separately.

For instance, if you want to install a new plugin 'a.vim', you just need to add a line into your bundle.vim 
`Bundle 'a.vim'` (for any plugins you can access from [VimScripts](http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html) you could just type the short name like 'c.vim' or 'Tagbar'). Restart Vim and run `:BundleInstall`, Vim will install the new plugins automatically.

In the same way, when you want to uninstall the plugin, just remove the line `Bundle 'a.vim'` in your configuration file and run `:BundleClean`, the plugin will be removed automatically.

Comment: I had been using bundle. I deleted all plugins and ran `:BundleClean`.